# How to use a intent in android?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, sony, sony-smartwatch

I have a sony smart watch and i'm trying to invoke a vibration intent by using the following:

```
Intent intentImplicit = new Intent(Control.Intents.CONTROL_VIBRATE_INTENT);
startActivity(intentImplicit);
```

it says startActivity its not declared in the control extension. How can I fix this?
 I found this online "You can get a Context object from the Constructor for the Control and save it to a member variable then just call context.startActivity()." but i'm unsure on how to do this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What is the purpose of trying to send that Intent?  If you are just trying to activate the Vibration, there is already a method built into the utilities class to do this.  Take a look at the ControlExtension.startVibrator() method in the SmartExtensionUtils project.

Comment: Does not work. The method startVibrator(int, int, int) from the type ControlExtension is not visible

Comment: Where did you find the startVibrator method?

Comment: Can you please tell me where you found it? I can't find anything on that project linking to that at all

Answer (score 1):

The Sony SDK documentation says you should use `sendBroadcast()`

See: http://developer.sonymobile.com/reference/sony-addon-sdk/com/sonyericsson/extras/liveware/aef/control/Control.Intents#CONTROL_VIBRATE_INTENT

So this should work:

```
context.sendBroadcast(intentImplicit, Registration.HOSTAPP_PERMISSION);
```

If you used a sample application from Sony as base, the context is already saved as a field of your class. If not, you can get a reference in the constructor of the Extension and save it to a field like this:

```
public class TestExtension extends ControlExtension 
{
    private Context context;

    TestExtension(final String hostAppPackageName, final Context context, Handler handler) 
    {
        super(context, hostAppPackageName);
        this.context = context;
    }
}
```

Comment: You might want to consider explaining how you how/where you got that `context` variable from.

Comment: the context is already saved as a field of your class.  Meaning?

Comment: updated solution to see how you get the context in the constructor